# What are some Seafoam Alternatives

Tags: cleaning, fuel-injection, intake-manifold, crankcase

I read [this procedure](http://www.nicoclub.com/archives/how-to-use-seafoam-to-clean-your-engine-the-right-way.html) for using Sea Foam ( [also listed on their website](http://seafoamsales.com/vacuum-line-method-with-sea-foam/) ) to clean the intake manifold, injectors and crankcase.  I think this would be useful for my vehicle, however Sea Foam isn't available where I live.

There are some [Liqui Moly made products](http://www.liqui-moly.de/liquimoly/produktdb.nsf/id/en_2822.html?Opendocument&land=GB) available here and I was thinking about using one of them. They list a bunch of different products [with different purposes here](http://www.liqui-moly.de/liquimoly/mediendb.nsf/gfx/2D2A7C2D3D0CCA42C12573DA00315AAF/$file/5616.pdf), such an oil sludge flush and engine flush in addition to regular injector cleaner.

**Could I use any injection system cleaner with the above procedure or do I need specialized products?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**tl dr** - To directly answer the question, SeaFoam is a pure petroleum product. If an alternative product is made up the same as Seafoam, then I'd think it would work just fine. If its makeup is not similar, you probably won't see the same results. Below is what you are looking for and a recipe for making your own substitute.

I found [this answer](http://hildstrom.com/projects/seafoam/) for a SeaFoam substitute online with a very nice write-up.

Basically, the guy broke down what SeaFoam is by looking up the formula on [Material Safety Data Sheets](http://seafoamsales.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/MSDS_seafoam_EN.pdf). This boils down to three parts: pale oil (ie: diesel fuel), Naphtha, and Isopropyl Alcohol (IPA). Note how all three are petroleum based in one form or another. This is the same as what SeaFoam claims for their product. His suggestions as far as how much of each would be:

```
4 parts diesel
2 parts naphtha
1 part IPA
```

The IPA he suggests needs to be fairly pure IPA and not what you purchase from the drug store. His suggestion is Iso-Heat, but I'm sure that most of the gasoline drying treatments are probably right in-line with this product. Read the back label and get the highest % you can find.

He suggests this worked very well, had nearly the same specific gravity as SeaFoam, was the same basic color as SeaFoam, and did not separate (just like SeaFoam). His write-up seems fairly comprehensive and makes a lot of sense. It sounds as though he's done his research and has come up with a viable alternative. This would also be a lot cheaper than buying SeaFoam, though I haven't found it cost prohibitive.

**NOTE:** While this may or may not be exactly what SeaFoam is and may work as the author suggests, you will want to make/use at your own risk. I take no responsibility for anything you do to your own vehicle.

**EDIT:** - As an aside, I prefer [this write-up](http://ls1tech.com/forums/general-maintenance-repairs/534376-how-seafoam-your-car.html) on using Seafoam. It is *very* complete, understandable, and (weeeeee) *has pictures!*

Comment: Upvoted for great info, and I might even try it, but it didn't actually answer the question I asked.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - Please see addition at the top of the answer. I apologize because I actually meant to have that in there.

Comment: Found naptha paint thinner and IPA locally, so I'm going to give it a try.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - Awesome Sauce! Let me know how it goes '-)

Comment: A little late, but thought I'd let you know that this stuff works great via the vacuum hose.  Verified with my endoscope afterwards that the backs of the valves and pistons were quite obviously cleaner.

Comment: @RobertS.Barnes - Awesome feedback! Thanks for following up.