# Look at the Valves Without Taking Everything Apart

Tags: cleaning

I was thinking it would be nice if I could look at the valves without having to take too much stuff apart.  Could I thread a small endoscope down through the air intake and be able to see the top / backside of a valve?  Could I put one ( bent backwards ) down the spark plug hole to see the cylinder side of the valve?  It would be cool if I could do a before and after of how cruddy the valves are when I [psuedo-seafoam](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/16486/what-are-some-seafoam-alternatives) the intake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool you seek is commonly known as a *borescope*, which should allow you to inspect both sides of the valves if you can get the scope end to reach there.

Here is a nice YouTube video showing the inspection of the piston surface and cylinder-facing side of the valve: https://youtu.be/LgbhePnUHiI

Comment: They're also called endoscopes - same thing just a different name.

Comment: Haha! That engine could use a Seafoam treatment '-)